# How can I forbid text flipping with css or jquery?

Tags: css, text, rotation, flip

When an object is rotated +180° everything inside it gets flipped so that it is still readable (I guess), I want to avoid that , how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your text in a div and rotate it with an opposite value of the degree that you assign to your parent div:

```
div.flipped {
    background: lightblue;
    padding-left: 150px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
}

div.noflipped {
    background: lightblue;
    padding-left: 150px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uTGXx/7/

Comment: Your fiddle also demonstrates an application of over-riding inherited property values.  Some novices may not notice that initially.

Comment: you should always specify the non-prefixed version of a style (eg `transform`) as well as the prefixed versions (eg `-moz-transform`).